# Intellij cannot locate library dependency from jitpack

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, build.gradle, intellij-plugin, jitpack

I started a basic intellij plugin in intellij IDEA and added this dependency to my gradle.build as per the jitpack directions:
https://github.com/ballerina-platform/lsp4intellij

https://jitpack.io/#ballerina-platform/lsp4intellij

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.5.2'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.ballerina-platform:lsp4intellij:Tag'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version = '2021.3.2'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes = """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I'm getting an error that the library cannot be found.  This is the error when I run gradle build --warning-mode=all

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':prepareSandbox'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.ballerina-platform:lsp4intellij:Tag.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/ballerina-platform/lsp4intellij/Tag/lsp4intellij-Tag.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/ballerina-platform/lsp4intellij/Tag/lsp4intellij-Tag.pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the 'Tag' part at the end of the dependency was the problem. This, copied from another project that uses the library seems to work!

```
implementation 'com.github.ballerina-platform:lsp4intellij:0.94.2'
```